# Cancel Rails DB connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing an app that uses Server Side events with ActionController::Live. It is using the puma app server. A method in the Messages controller stays alive while the user is connected waiting for messages from Redis.

The problem is that I don't want to connect to Postgres on this method. After I open the app in six tabs it has over five connections defined by the pool size in the `config/database.yml` file and the app crashes.

Is there anyway to tell my app when that method is called it doesn't need to connect to the database as there is no ActiveRecord query calls in it?

Comment: Should I just be putting it at the top of my controller action because it didn't work.

Comment: can you post a rails app as sample which reproduces this issue of app crash?

Comment: You'll need to increase the number of DB connections to equal the number of Puma threads. Otherwise you prematurely run out of connections, like you're seeing.

Comment: Yes but what I really wanted is a way in which when puma threads are created, a new database connection isn't created as it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is to use middleware.  A good resource for setting up your own middleware is http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast

However, I'm not convinced that the problem you're experiencing is because of too many connections to Postgres.  This is just a hunch, but I think your problem may lie elsewhere.